# lucene query issue

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I am using Lucene with Alfresco. Here is my query:

```
( TYPE:"{com.company.customised.content.model}test"  &&  (@\{com.company.customised.content.model\}testNo:111 && (@\{com.company.customised.content.model\}skill:or))
```

I have to search documents which are having property skill of value `"or"`. The above query is not giving any results (I am getting failed to parse query).

If I use the query up until `testNo` (ignoring `skill`), I am getting proper results:

```
 ( TYPE:"{com.company.customised.content.model}test"  &&  (@\{com.company.customised.content.model\}testNo:111))
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `"or"` is a reserved keyword in Lucene. Therefore, Lucene fails to properly interpret your query, because Lucene thinks you are referring to the [`OR` boolean operator](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators). You may want to try wrapping the `or` in double quotes:

```
( TYPE:"{com.company.customised.content.model}test"  &&  (@\{com.company.customised.content.model\}testNo:111 && (@\{com.company.customised.content.model\}skill:"or"))
```

I am not familiar with Alfresco, so you may not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , or is reserved keyword in lucene but if you are trying to query by property which is of type number then you can give your value directly else if of type d:text or string so that you have to gave your value in double quote **" "** .

( TYPE:"{com.company.customised.content.model}test"  &&  (@{com.company.customised.content.model}testNo:111 && (@{com.company.customised.content.model}skill:"or"))